# bug in shell scripting basic program

Tags: shell, sh, ubuntu-13.10

Following is the code that I have copied from a book but its not working properly

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "is it morning?reply with yes or no"
read timeof

if [ $timeof="yes" ]
then
echo "Good morning"
else
echo "Good afternoon"
fi

exit 0
```

when I am giving the input yes it gives the output as good morning but it gives good morning for no as well. Also after a while it says good afternoon for both yes and no. This is really frustrating please help.

~
~

Comment: shouldn't it be -eq instead of =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equal sign should have a space character on either side. Note it does not allow for timeof being null.  extra credit for you to fix :-)

Comment: yes thank you , that solved it. So while assigning a variable one must not use spaces on either side but while checking conditions it is necessary. The null problem can be solved by using double quotes on both sides ?

Comment: If you want to test explicitly for null, use -z.  Read up on the "test" command ("[" is typically a link to "test").  As written, your program will print "Good afternoon" if the user entered "no" or just pressed enter on a blank line. Oh I would suggest you use /bin/bash as /bin/sh is an older shell.  At any rate, when looking up info, make sure you are reading the man page for the right shell.

Answer (score 2):

Besides adding spaces around `=` as mentioned by [Gary_W](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24786436/445221), enclose your arguments around double quotes as well when necessary to prevent word splitting and unexpected pathname expansions.

```
if [ "$timeof" = yes ]
```